# how do I update a single template thats connected to multiple websites in pantheon

Tags: wordpress, git, drupal, web-hosting, pantheon

I'm using pantheon to host multiple WordPress sites. All the sites are using the same theme and I want to know if there is a way for me to make changes to an individual sites theme that would update them all and make work easier.

Comment: Same template?! You mean same theme?

Comment: yes thats exactly what I meant

Comment: If they are on same server you can have real theme directory on one site and link to that directory in all other sites, so they will share the same theme directory. Or if you use git maybe you can set auto deploy to all sites... Still your questions is not very clear...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Pantheon Custom Upstreams: https://pantheon.io/docs/custom-upstream/

If you are dealing with individual websites, you can transition them all to a custom upstream and life gets a lot easier.

If you are dealing with multi-site then the answer is, just change the Theme because they all point to the same codebase.